# multi store view sitemap.xml url rewrite

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, htaccess, sitemaps

I have magento multi store view installation with structure like this:

```
example.com/it
example.com/fr
example.com/de
```

I wan't to configure sitemap.xml for every store view. Sitemap.xml files are generated in

```
example.com/sitemaps/it
example.com/sitemaps/fr
example.com/sitemaps/de
```

maps, which I did created manually.

Now I wan't to have sitemap.xml files accessible (for google webmaster tools) like this:

```
example.com/it/sitemap.xml
example.com/fr/sitemap.xml
example.com/de/sitemap.xml
```

Any suggestions hot to achieve this? Or maybe some better approach for my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using an http rewrite rule.
Add the following line inside your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(sitemap.xml) /sitemaps/$1/sitemap.xml [L,NC]
```

after

```
RewriteEngine on
```

To use a default store code if none specified in the url, add the following line after the previous one:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)sitemap.xml /sitemaps/it/sitemap.xml [L,NC]
```

(Obviously you can use other default store code)

Comment: Thanks! It's working. One more thing. How can I rewrite example.com/sitemap.xml to example.com/it/sitemap.xml?

Comment: I've edited the answer. You just need to add another rule after the first one