# multistore sitemap rewrite /sitemaps/domainname.com/sitemap.xml

Tags: url-rewrite, htaccess

is there an easy way to rewrite our sitemap to Magento sitemap directory?

**So:**

- example.com/sitemap.xml
- www.example.com/sitemap.xml
- anotherexample.com/sitemap.xml
- www.anotherexample.com/sitemap.xml

**get redirected to**

- example.com/sitemaps/example.com/sitemap.xml
- example.com/sitemaps/example.com/sitemap.xml
- anotherexample.com/sitemaps/anotherexample.com/sitemap.xml
- anotherexample.com/sitemaps/anotherexample.com/sitemap.xml

I was looking at this, but just not the same: [multi store view sitemap.xml url rewrite](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24291/multi-store-view-sitemap-xml-url-rewrite)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When generating the sitemap you can fill in the folder where it should be created. Just create the folder structure you need and fill in the path field with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Nginx we succeeded in doing just that using

```
location ~* /sitemap\.xml$ {
    rewrite ^(/..)?/sitemap.xml$ $1/sitemaps/$storecode/sitemap.xml permane$
}
```

What is does is:
filter for sitemap.xml
rewrite to folder /sitemaps/{MAGE_RUN_CODE}/sitemap.xml
Works perfectly
As long as your {MAGE_RUN_CODE} detection is flawless

The added `(/..)?` adds support for example.com/en and example.com/fr language sites and should be adjusted when creating other subdirectories

Good luck